# Axios REST api client pagination

Tags: javascript, python, flask, pagination, axios

I have a problem. I have a rest api in flask application. Application is connected to database which stores 10k users. I need to do something like a pagination. I want to get for example: list of 100 users, from 1 to 100, and then get an url to next page with users from 101 to 200 etc. I made a axios request like this:

```
document.getElementById('showUserInputForm').addEventListener('submit', performGetRequest1);
function performGetRequest1(){
  var start = document.getElementById('starting').value;
  var limit = document.getElementById('limit').value;
  var resultElement = document.getElementById('getResult1');
  resultElement.innerHTML = '';

  axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/users/page', {
    params: {
      start:start,
      limit:limit
    }
  })
    .then(function (response) {
     resultElement.innerHTML = generateSuccessHTMLOutput(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
     resultElement.innerHTML = generateErrorHTMLOutput(error);
    });
}
```

This code returns me json:

```
{
    "limit": 100,
    "next": "users/page?start=200&limit=100",
    "previous": "users/page?start=1&limit=99",
    "results": [
        {
{
        "id": 101,
        "password": "hicqjjzxftvq",
        "username": "jclkoxgwgvvw"
    },
    {
         "id": 100,
         "password": "xtitexyetpwg",
         "username": "uwerzuwnxkju"
    },
```

How i can use these next/previous links to make < and > buttons with it? Or any ideas how to make it?

Comment: Whats the problem here?

Comment: The problem is, how to "take" links nex and previous from json return and put them as buttons in the way:
1. I click next then the return is from 100 to 200, 
2. again next: return from 200 to 300
3. more more

Comment: So basically you're asking how to change the `href` of a link? Your question really doesn't have anything to do with paging.

Comment: It won't be the href - I assume he doesn't want a navigation event to take place, since it looks like the generateSuccessHTMLOutput(response) is creating HTML from the list of items that would be filled into resultElement. I think he's asking how to store the previous and next URLs that get returned, and how to associate them with a button so that it knows which URL to use when either one is clicked (without navigating away from the page).

Comment: Yeah Joseph thats what i need

Comment: @MrSzegerege Did NelisV's answer work for you, or are you still looking for a solution?

Comment: @Joseph still looking :(

Comment: If its still unanswered in a bit, I'll work up a codepen example for you to make sure we can get it running.

Comment: I will be gratefull !

Comment: @MrSzegerege okay, I built off of NelisV's answer. Take a look at this JSFiddle. Ignore everything below the nextPage function in the script section - I made a fake axios so we could keep it looking similar. Uncomment the parts I commented and put it into your environment. What should happen is when the page first loads, the initial URL (/users/page) is hit. When you get the response back, we store the variables in nextUrl and previousUrl. Then, when you click either arrow, we retrieve that URL and tell performGetRequest1 to use it for the API call. https://jsfiddle.net/graneyc8/7/

Comment: @MrSzegerege right now, my fake axios returns the same next and previous urls each time, but your axios request will get the real values from your server. Just make sure you don't copy over the var axios = { section.

Comment: @Joseph Thanks! I Will try it in the morning and i will let u know it worked ! Many thanks for help!

Comment: No worries! Let me know if you have any issues. Good luck!

Comment: There is again a problem: "GET /undefined HTTP/1.1" 404 - when i try to get to next url, its like next url is not passed by func or what? The function dont catch the next.response i think, beacuse even when i set: nextUrl = url + response.next; i get : "GET /users/pageundefined HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: It worked. Problem was " response.next" change for " response.data.next".

Comment: @Joseph, mayby u got idea, how to search results for example username, i mean to add some space to pass username, then click search and it will show it

Comment: @MrSzegerege Good catch on the response.data! The response format varies, so it's always a good idea to check on that first thing. For your searching mechanism, take a look at this JSFiddle. It will iterate through all of the results from your API (just store your response and change apiResponse to use that instead), then adds a list of the matching usernames to the page. https://jsfiddle.net/L5v6stec/5/

Answer (score 0):

The backend actually returns the endpoints you can use for the next / previous page.

You can do something like this:

```
let nextUrl = null;
let previousUrl = null;
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/users/page';

function performGetRequest1(url){
  var start = document.getElementById('starting').value;
  var limit = document.getElementById('limit').value;
  var resultElement = document.getElementById('getResult1');
  resultElement.innerHTML = '';

  axios.get(url)
    .then(function (response) {
     resultElement.innerHTML = generateSuccessHTMLOutput(response);
     nextUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/' + response.next;
     previousUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/' + response.previous;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
     resultElement.innerHTML = generateErrorHTMLOutput(error);
    });
}
```

If you run this function using either the `nextUrl` or `previousUrl` it should return the correct values.

Comment: Great i was looking for something like this, im new to js and i was thinking how to figure it out. And how to take nextUrl and prevUrl to buttons?

Comment: The simpel solution would be something like this in your HTML code.

**<a onClick="performGetRequest1(previousUrl)">Previous</a>
<a onClick="performGetRequest1(nextUrl)">Next</a>**

Comment: Please note that it doesn't escapes errors and is a bit quirky. You want to write some error handling for this.

Comment: Yeah but if i put:
    function performGetRequest1(url)

then i occur an error, when i use:

    function performGetRequest1()


its ok ;/

Comment: You're function need to accept a parameter, otherwise it doesn't work. 

You do this like **function MyFunction(parameter)```

Comment: Yeah but when i copy code you posted it occurs an error :/ Like function dont accept parameter url

Comment: And i have error and response outputs so thats not problem in there

Comment: I forgot to wrap the url in quotes =)

Comment: Yeah but it still have some problems and dont work properly ;/

Comment: The problem is it takes start and limit from params i think, not from url + response.next

Comment: Added a fix to my code. You need to rid the params of course :)

Comment: Hmm, in my flask get request with nexturl param is : " "GET /undefined?start=20&limit=20 HTTP/1.1" 404 -" idk why it takes this url, not next